# Database table populated, does not display

Tags: php, mysql, database

My company recently moved a php website to a new server. I updated all of the links and references to the database, etc. The problem is that in the new location the database is recognized and when the php page performs a sql query the results appear to be found but not displayed.

For example, if you log in as an admin and click on "People" it should list all of the members of the site. However, when you log in as admin and click "People" it displays 6 pages of blank lines (old site works fine). Am I missing something simple? Why can it read the info but not display it properly?

Comment: Seems like PHP config issue. Check register_globals, magic quotes and check for any mysql config issues in the php.ini.

Comment: Could it be a CSS issue?

Comment: @DWright , the CSS for the site has been untouched in the transfer?

Comment: This is pun but.... depending on the server the use of single & double quotes can make a difference when displaying the elements from your results array... array['col'] can yeild a different result to array["col"], i have seen this happen before...

Comment: @Djumaka the "register_globals" and "magic_quotes_gpc" are turned off in the .htaccess file. Nothing appears to be conflicting with the php.ini

Comment: Could it be displaying the values but the foreground color is the same as the background color?

Comment: Yeah, what Gordon said was what the direction I was thinking in.  View the underlying source of the html that is generated to see if the data is present, but is being formatted in such a way that it is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things to try/think about:

1. Turn on 'display_errors'
2. raise the reporting level and pay attention to notices.
3. Check for a different version of PHP
4. Specifically, look for differences in the MySQL functions/methods if the PHP version is different. This may affect the portion of code which iterates over your responses.

My gut says the problem will be in the line that iterates your results. Since it appears to be iterating the right number of times, but the data is not there, I suspect you are getting good results but not fetching them properly. This is feasible if there is a newer version of PHP involved.

Comment: The "display_errors" in the php.ini worked perfectly. Turns out the config file was pointed to documentroot/site and it needed to be documentroot/site/

Thanks for all the help!